# Why don't these arrays save the dynamically added text fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add multiple fields by clicking one plus button. Then I have four arrays for four specific text fields: `company`, `from`, `to`, and `year`. If I click the button, I will get the four fields. I want to enter values and have the values saved in the four arrays. When I click the button again the same thing should happen.

The array saves only the first value from each field and the other value is null. How can I save all of the values in the arrays?

```js
var company = [];
var from = [];
var to = [];
var year = [];

var scntDiv = $('#addmorefieldexp');
var i = $('#addmorefieldexp p').size() + 1;
               
/*    $('#pexp').live('click', function() */ 
$("#pexp").click(function(){
    $( ' <br><br>'
        +'<label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Company Name</label>'
        +'<div class="col-sm-2">'
        +'<input type="text" class="form-control" name="field_company[]" value="" id="company">'
        +'</div>'

        +'<label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">From</label>'
        +'<div class="col-sm-2">'
        +'<input type="text" class="form-control" name="field_from[]" value="" id="from">'
        +'</div>'
      
        +'<label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">To</label>'
        +'<div class="col-sm-2">'
        +'<input type="text" class="form-control" name="field_to[]"value="" id="to">'
        +'</div>'

        +'<label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Year</label>'
        +'<div class="col-sm-1">'
        +'<input type="text" class="form-control" name="field_year[]"value="" id="year">'
        +'</div>').appendTo(scntDiv);
   
    var add_company = $("input[name$='field_company[]']").val();
    company.push(add_company);
    
    var add_from = $("input[name$='field_from[]']").val();
    from.push(add_from);
    
    var add_to = $("input[name$='field_to[]']").val();
    to.push(add_to);
    
    var add_year = $("input[name$='field_year[]']").val();
    year.push(add_year);
  
    console.log(company, from, to, year);

    return false;                      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group" id="experience">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Employment Experience</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4" id="checkbox" value="">
    <input type="radio" name="exp" class="expp" value="Yes">Yes
    <input type="radio" name="exp" class="expp" value="No">No
    <button class="btn btn-lg  btn-sm btn-primary btn-circle" id="pexp"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group text-center" id="addmorefieldexp">
  <p>
  </p>
</div>
```

[image: There are two dynamically added fields, but there is only one value in the console and the other is null]

Comment: I see a lot of code that seems to be unrelated to this question (e.g. then `change` functions). If I'm right please remove any unnecessary code to make it easier for others to track down your problem.

Comment: Why you on `$('#pexp').live('click',` don't use `jQueryTemplate instead of concatenation strings`?

Comment: @gus27 , I have edited it

Comment: I cleaned up the question a little bit so that you can run it in a code snippet. I also added a `console.log` with the four arrays so that you can see what is being saved and when.

Comment: Thanks,but it's solved. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I is done!!! I have to add this to save value on the array.

```
var inps = document.getElementsByName('field_company[]');
        for (var i = 0; i <inps.length; i++) {
        var inp=inps[i];
            company.push(inp.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write a for loop to iterate through all of the input fields, like so:

```
var companyField = $("input[name$='field_company']");
for (var i;i<companyField.length;i++) {
    var companyValue = companyField[i].val();
    company.push(companyValue);
}

var fromField = $("input[name$='field_from']");
for (var i;i<fromField.length;i++) {
    var fieldValue = fromField[i].val();
    from.push(fieldValue);
}

var toField = $("input[name$='field_to']");
for (var i;i<toField.length;i++) {
    var toValue = toField[i].val();
    to.push(toValue);
}

var yearField = $("input[name$='field_year']");
for (var i;i<yearField.length;i++) {
    var yearValue = yearField[i].val();
    year.push(yearValue);
}
```